Does hemolymph qualify as blood?
Eating blood is prohibited. However, some creatures, such as locusts, have hemolymph instead of what we normally consider blood. Does hemolymph qualify as blood and, as a result, must be removed before consumption?
Note: While the question “Would Noahides be required to eat kosher meat?”  is related, it says nothing about hemolymph.

https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Yoreh_De'ah.66.1?lang=bi&with=all

The prohibition of consuming blood applies to poultry and to animals not insects. Of course that is assuming said locust are kosher. The same is true of fish. However, that is in a biblical level consuming this blood separate from the locust or fish would be prohibited by the rabbis because of maris ayin

Perhaps, the question should not be about hemolymph of locusts, but other kosher creatures if they have any hemolymph? I've never seen people draining fish. I did manage to get a real locust with my sun flower seeds in Jerusalem once, I did not try it, because I did not know if it was kosher. But it was not drained either, just salted.

@YDJ I’ve edited my question to make it clear that I’m not limiting my question to locusts. Any sources that explain whether hemolymph qualifies as blood would be helpful, even if it’s referring to shellfish like an oyster.

@TheEditor Shellfish are all non-kosher anyway, so you are unlikely to find discussion of the status of their blood, as it's more or less irrelevant

See shulchan aruch yoreh dea 66:9

Another relevant source is Mishnah Eduyot 7:2, which suggests that it is permissible to preserve locusts in brine. From what I understand, this method involves the entire locust, including the hemolymph.
